# How do I step through a fixed range in a loop in Kotlin where the step value changes on every iteration

Tags: kotlin

It seems Kotlin has taken away the ability to do common, basic loops or I haven't found the right documentation.

Given the following Java loop, I can roughly convert it to the kotlin below it (included so you can maybe understand where my current mistake has originated. This method was not easy to discover, so it may not be the correct approach at all)

```
for (int i=start; i < end; i++)   // base java
for (i in start until end)        // equivalent kotlin
```

But what about when I need to support stepping instead of incrementing one at a time? Given this Java loop:

```
for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
    int count = 1
    //stuff that assigns count
    offset += count;
}
```

This Kotlin "equivalent" code gives an assignment error because `i` is in fact a `val` not a `var` (and I may not declare it as a `var`):

```
for (i in offset until length) {
    var count = 1
    //stuff that assigns count
    offset += count;
}
```

**How do I step through a fixed range, where the step value changes on every iteration?**

Comment: In Kotlin, `for` iterates over only iterators. So unless you can abstract away the stepping in an iterator, you'll have to use a `while` loop

Comment: thanks @Peter, that might be why I could't find what I was looking for then since I've been googling for-loops specifically. An answer with the actual syntax would be useful to close this question. It seem like while still requires me to make a var outside of the loop

Comment: It does require declaration outside the loop statement - it would be the same as in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, a proper example:

```
var i = 0

while (i < end) {
    val count = 1

    i += count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax in Java

```java
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

}
```

is shorthand for

```java
int i = 0;
while (i < length) {

    i++;
}
```

for which the equivalent Kotlin code would be

```kotlin
var i = 0
while (i < length) {

    i++
}
```

Likewise, your example code

```java
for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
    int count = 1;
    //stuff that assigns count
    offset += count;
}
```

is shorthand for

```java
int offset = 0;
while (offset < length) {
    int count = 1;
    //stuff that assigns count
    offset += count;
}
```

for which the equivalent Kotlin code is:

```kotlin
var offset = 0
while (offset < length) {
    var count = 1
    //stuff that assigns count
    offset += count
}
```